# SQL UPDATE query executes correctly via MySQL Workbench but not via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE uploads SET UserName='Test2', UserEmail='Test2', UploadCount='4' 
WHERE Country = 'Algeria'
```

When I run this query via MySQL workbench it executes fine.

I am trying to run this via a website / PHP however, and am attempting to execute the query in the following way:

```
$sql = "UPDATE uploads SET UserName='$user_data[name]', UserEmail='$user_data[email]', UploadCount='$user_data[FilesUploaded]' WHERE Country = '$country'";


echo $sql;  
    try 

    {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db01', $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();       

  # Affected Rows?
      echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

The SQL query is being built via variables here, however I copy / pasted the echo of $sql into workbench to check that there were no syntax errors creeping in, the echo of $sql is what I pasted above.

When I run it via the web application, I get 0 row affected and the UPDATE is not made, where am I going wrong?

Thank you

UPDATE: A new paramatarized version of the PDO:

```
$sql =  "UPDATE uploads SET ";

$sql .="UserName = :name, 
        UserEmail = :email, 
        UploadCount = :FilesUploaded";

$sql .=" WHERE Country = '$country'";

    try     
    {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db01', $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $user_data['name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $user_data['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":FilesUploaded", $user_data['FilesUploaded']);

    $stmt->execute();       

  # Affected Rows?
      echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: parameterized the values `:)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that, could you clarify? :)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: ok, is this required to execute the query, or just preferable? I haven't used this method in the past.

Comment: well it's a must-learn-to-do in order to have queries which always run good and in order to keep away sql injection

Comment: Ok, thanks! I've implemented a paramaterized version, which runs with no errors, however it is still not updating my table as expected. I'm concerned I've created the table wrongly.

Comment: Can you update with your new parameterized version?

Comment: Of course, thanks - have done this now.

Comment: @tadman I'm wondering if I have constructed the table I'm trying to update incorrectly (I'm new to it) and as such PDO isn't happy making edits to it? I have a Primary Unique Non Null Index, but other than that I just made fields.

Comment: If you're parameterizing your queries, please, do parameterize **all** of them. It's very worrying to see `$country` in there waiting for a chance to be a gigantic [SQL injection vulnerability](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: PDO will only work if the schema allows it, it's true. Is there any reason to be using country names, which are highly subjective, rather than [two letter ISO-3166 country codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)? Mistakes are easy to make if you don't standardize. Maybe `$country` is empty, or not capitalized correctly. This is why forcing uppercase is usually better.

Comment: $country is defined via a form input on a prior page which posts the data, and it is defined via a dropdown. It's a very specific set of country spellings that is in line with the organization standard, which is different from the international standard. Although it's still possible to inject by changing the DOM, so I should change it, it's not the source of this error. I can confirm this by the fact that if I copy paste the echo of the query, it runs fine via workbench.

Comment: @tadman well, you were right regarding the ill advised usage of country names, it was a white space getting into the query that was messing it up, and, I think, a character set mis match between my web page and the database: I took your advice and set up a paired array of ISO standard 3 letter codes and their names, and then operated the database of the ISO standard and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Gideon Good to hear that worked for you. Sticking to a standard also makes your data more compatible with other sources.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to insert information from an array while it's in quotes. Try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE uploads SET UserName='".$user_data['name']."', UserEmail='".$user_data['email']."', UploadCount='".$user_data['FilesUploaded']."' WHERE Country = '$country'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the $sql variable does seem to be being defined as a valid SQL query, as shown by the fact that if I echo $sql and run the query in workbench, it works fine. I implemented your edit just in case however, but it made no difference.

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** inline data in the query. Changing the quoting is not the solution.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that there is a row in your database with the country 'Algeria' ?

Comment: Absolutely, the possible range of $country and is defined by the contents of the database's 'Country' field.